# HDLC as Character Driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, network-driver

We have a working network interface driver for HDLC protocol. Customer requirement is to have a character driver like UART. Is it possible to re write it as a character driver? Google search gives me [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.arch.embedded/6L1DBDoFbxM) which from 2000.

Had anyone come across HDLC protocol driver character based?

Comment: Strange requirements. It’s of course possible **to extend ** (no need to rewrite), but maybe they need a `socat `?

Comment: Can you give more detail about which extend it is possible? We needs to load UART and HDLC in same port such that when the port is acting as HDLC, UART shouldn't be configured and vice versa. So, they thought its better to have HDLC as /dev/tty kind of driver instead of network interface driver.

Comment: They can run `socat` between network interface and whtever other end which requires UART. I don't see why kernel needs to be modified at all.

Comment: Both UART and HDLC needs to be present in same port. Depends on customer choice, it should work either as HDLC or UART.

Comment: I guess somebody (presumable me) doesn't understand **why** this requirement is needed and what's wrong with network interface.

Comment: The Microgate SyncLink drivers in drivers/tty/synclink*.c do this sort of thing, so it is possible.